# How can I email multiple camera roll images at once on an iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, email, photos

When looking at my photos, I see that I can view a picture, click on the button the bottom left, and then click "Email Photo" but I now want to be able to email multiple photos into a single email.

Is this possible on the latest iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this works the same as on my iPhone 3Gs, you´ll want to go into the photo roll (not show an actual photo) and then tap the "share" button in the upper right corner (the one that looks like an arrow pointing out of a square) - you will then be able to select up to five images and tap on "send" to send them as an e-Mail.

Comment: You can also tap on Copy to copy the images to the clipboard and paste them into the email. You can do this to get around the 5 image limit.